# Can't create new table

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm new to SQL Server 2000 and face a problem. I want to make a new table but I encounter an error message with the following code:

```
create table Buku
(
Kode_Buku char(5) constraint PK_Kode_Buku Primary Key,
Judul_Buku varchar(10)not null,
Nama_Pengarang varchar(30) not null,
Penerbit varchar(30),
Kota_Terbit varchar(30) default,
Tahun_Terbit varchar(4) default,
Bahasa varchar(4) check,
Harga_Jual money,
)
```

and here's the error code:

> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'Buku'.

Comment: You're "new" to SQL Server 2000? You know that SQL Server 2000 is 13 years old and at the end of extended support, right? Any reason you don't want to use any of the 4 major versions that have been released since then (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012)?

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems:

1. You have multiple cases where you say `default` but don't specify anything
2. You have a `check` but don't specify anything
3. Your last column definition says `money,` with a trailing comma

Now, none of these lead to the exact error message you're getting, so maybe there is more you're not telling us (is there more code *before* the `create table` bit?), but these little syntax problems are far too localized to be useful in this Q & A format.

**EDIT**

I just ran this on a SQL Server 2000 instance and it worked just fine:

```
create table Buku 
(
  Kode_Buku char(5) constraint PK_Kode_Buku Primary Key, 
  Judul_Buku varchar(10) not null, -- added space here
  Nama_Pengarang varchar(30) not null, 
  Penerbit varchar(30), 
  Kota_Terbit varchar(30), -- removed default here
  Tahun_Terbit varchar(4), -- removed default here
  Bahasa varchar(4), -- removed check here
  Harga_Jual money -- removed comma here
)
```

So I'm not sure what you're doing differently, but I can't get the error message you are seeing with the information you've provided in the question. If you're still getting an error message with this code (and only this code), you'll need to provide more information, such as @@VERSION, what interface you're using to submit the create table statement to SQL Server, etc.

Comment: there's no more code before create table, it just don't work. i tried to find an answer via google but i don't get any. Maybe because i'm using old version of sql? or the there's something i have to set when create a database?

Comment: thank you so much for your help, now i can compile it without errors. i'm sorry it took so long to response. once again thank you.